# ggplot geom_polygon connections false if xlim/ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a heat map to a map with ggplot (which works fine), but if I restrict the axes, my geom_polygon overlay connects the points in a wrong way.

```
ggplot(2017.fixes, aes(x=Long, y=Lat) ) +
    stat_density_2d(aes(fill = ..density..), geom = "raster", contour=F)+
    scale_fill_distiller(palette="PuBu", direction=1) +
    geom_polygon (data=map.df,aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group), color="grey50", fill="grey", na.rm=T) +
    #xlim(-156.95, -156.4)+
    #ylim(20.55, 21.05 )+
    coord_fixed()
```

produces this:

[image: Complete map]

But if I uncomment xlim and ylim I get this:

[image: Zoomed in map]

It obviously cuts off the left island correctly, but not the other two, and I don't exactly know why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
xlim(-156.95, -156.4) +
ylim(20.55, 21.05) +
coord_fixed()
```

Use:

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-156.95, -156.4), ylim = c(20.55, 21.05)) +
```

This restricts the axes without removing data.

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html

---

Also try `coord_map` for plotting maps.

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_map.html

---

Comment: Thank you! However, when I use this, it still produces the first plot with the complete area. If I take out coord_fixed(), it restricts the axes, but is all distorted. I think this is because it fits it to a square instead of the original rectangle the coordinates create. Is there a way to keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: That's because `coord_fixed` overrides `coord_cartesian`. You can solve this by making sure the axes limits are equally spaced. However, for plotting geographical data, you could try `coord_map`. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_map.html . It's hard to suggest without creation of a reproducible example where we can use your data.